# Derbyjs Cannot call method expose of undefined

Tags: derbyjs

I want to extends query method of model, this is what i wrote:

```
store.query.expose('todos', 'forGroup', function(group) {
return this.where('group').equals(group);
});
```

but when i run the app, console says "Cannot call method expose of undefined", which means store.query is undefined.**Why is that?**

the store variable is:

```
var store = derby.createStore({
db: liveDbMongo(mongoUrl + '?auto_reconnect', {safe: true})
, redis: redis
});
```

And i also output the store using console.log:

```
{ domain: null,
  _events: { client: [Function] },
  _maxListeners: 10,
  racer: 
   { get: [Function],
     _plugins: [ [Function: derbyServer] ],
     run: [Function: run],
     createApp: [Function: createApp],
     createStatic: [Function: createStatic] },
  modelOptions: undefined,
  shareClient: 
   { options: { db: [Object], redis: [Object] },
     preValidate: undefined,
     validate: undefined,
     backend: 
      { snapshotDb: [Object],
        getOps: [Function],
        publish: [Function],
        submit: [Function],
        _subscribeChannels: [Function],
        subscribe: [Function],
        fetch: [Function],
        bulkFetchCached: [Function],
        fetchAndSubscribe: [Function],
        queryFetch: [Function],
        query: [Function],
        collection: [Function],
        destroy: [Function] },
     extensions: { '': [] },
     docFilters: [],
     opFilters: [] },
  logger: undefined }
```

and `console.log(store.query)` outputs `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

The Access Control Api was changed in the 0.5 version of Racer, which is mentioned here http://blog.derbyjs.com/2013/06/04/migrating-from-derby-0-dot-3-to-0-dot-5/

I have not played around that much with authentication, but a pointer is to look through the Auth example on GitHub - https://github.com/codeparty/derby-examples/tree/master/auth.